# Expected(200) <=> Actual(401 Unauthorized) in Heroku console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

This just started happening. Whenever I open the console in my production app (via Heroku CLI), I get this message.

```
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL

Expected(200) <=> Actual(401 Unauthorized)
  request => {:connect_timeout=>60, :headers=>{"Accept"=>"application/json", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip", "Authorization"=>"Basic OmQ5NDc0NTY0LWUwMDMtNDRlYy1hYTJjLTUxODYwMTI5YzA5Zg==", "User-Agent"=>"heroku-rb/0.2.1", "X-Heroku-API-Version"=>"3", "X-Ruby-Version"=>"2.0.0", "X-Ruby-Platform"=>"x86_64-linux", "Host"=>"api.heroku.com:443"}, :instrumentor_name=>"excon", :mock=>false, :read_timeout=>60, :retry_limit=>4, :ssl_ca_file=>"/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/excon-0.13.4/data/cacert.pem", :ssl_verify_peer=>true, :write_timeout=>60, :host=>"api.heroku.com", :path=>"/apps/staging-xxxx/ps", :port=>"443", :query=>nil, :scheme=>"https", :expects=>200, :method=>:get}
  response => #<Excon::Response:0x007f2ecf385658 @body="{\"id\":\"unauthorized\",\"error\":\"Invalid credentials provided.\"}", @headers={"Cache-Control"=>"no-transform", "Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Date"=>"Tue, 28 Apr 2015 18:40:19 GMT", "Request-Id"=>"53c8af5d-0d1c-46bf-8779-e5f6d6c8cd1a", "Server"=>"nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)", "Status"=>"401 Unauthorized", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "X-Runtime"=>"0.015607713", "Content-Length"=>"61", "Connection"=>"keep-alive"}, @status=401>
Expected(200) <=> Actual(401 Unauthorized)
```

Console still opens, but wondering why I now get this message every time I open the prod console. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the **delayed_job_recurring** gem. I removed the gem and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

You are fresh out of API tokens, using delayed job with workless are we?

Comment: I'm using the delayed_job gem and have a dedicated worker for background jobs. I'm not using workless.

Comment: Doh.... heroku accounts gem? ... Alternatively... are you using workless on any other APP associated with the same heroku account?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured out it was an issue with a gem, see my answer.